# How to write Rspec spec for the following query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

Hi I have the following query in my controller and I want to write the Rspec spec . I am new to Rspec and I don't know how to write the spec. Kindly help

```
table1.includes(:table2).where(table1: {id: params[:id]}).includes(:table3)
```

I also tried looking into mocks and stubs but i don't understand how to use them for a query like this.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to test?

Comment: Are you trying to figure test that it runs within a certain time, that it's "correct" and returns the results expected, or something else? You need to know what you want to test before we can help.

Comment: @ChrisHeald , Normalocity - I want to make sure the query returns the required result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When faced with these issues, I tend to encapsulate the query in a method. That way, you can stub out the method with data simply and without worrying about data-sanitation.

For example:

```
def fetch_table1_results(id)
  table1.includes(:table2).where(table1: {id: id}).includes(:table3)
end
```

At this point, you can stub out the method when you need to test things that depend on it:

```
awesome_model = stub_model(Table1, fetch_table1_results: [1, 2, 'etc']) # You should include models, stubs, or mocks here.
```

---

As far as testing the actual method, I'm not sure you need to. There aren't many interesting parts of that method chain. If you wanted to be complete, here are the cases:

- Ensure `fetch_table1_results` calls any instance of Table1.find with id
- Ensure `fetch_table1_results` eager-loads `table2` and `table3`

The way of doing the latter varies, but I'm rather fond (and this won't be a popular opinion) of checking the database query directly. So you could type something like the following:

`fetch_table1_results(1).to_sql.should include('JOIN table2')`

That, or something similar. I should also note that these tests should be in the model, not the controller.